# How to tell the MinGW linker not to export all symbols?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, gcc, g++

I'm building a Windows dynamic library using the MinGW toolchain.

To build this library I'm statically linking to other 2 which offer an API and I have a `.def` file where I wrote the only symbol I want to be exported in my library.

The problem is that GCC is exporting all of the symbols including the ones from the libraries I'm linking to. Is there anyway to tell the linker just to export the symbols in the `def` file?

I know there is the option `--export-all-symbols` but there seems not to be the opposite to it.

Right now the last line of the build script has this structure:

```
g++ -shared CXXFLAGS DEFINES INCLUDES -o library.dll library.cpp DEF_FILE \
OBJECT_FILES LIBS -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup
```

EDIT: In the [docs](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32) about the linker it says that `--export-all-symbols` is the default behavior and that it's disabled when you don't use that option explicitly if you provide a `def` file, except when it doesn't; the symbols in 3rd party libs are being exported anyway.

EDIT: Adding the option `--exclude-libs LIBS` or `–exclude-symbols SYMBOLS` doesn't prevent the symbols from the libraries from being exported.

Comment: `--exclude-libs ALL` option would be interesting to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dllwrap if your distribution of binutils (either native or cross compiling) provides it.

It can produce DLLs using the interface in a DEF file (under the hood it calls gcc, ld and dlltool to do so). The difference between using this and passing a DEF file to GCC directly is that the definitions in the file are treated differently.

For example, if you have a symbol rename in the export file:

```
_SomeFuntion = _SomeFunction@12
```

GCC will create 2 exports, one by the name of `_SomeFunction` and the other one with the decorated name while dllwrap will only export `_SomeFuntion`. So if you only add to the DEF file the symbols you want to be exported you will end up only with them in the library.

dllwrap by default uses the C compiler driver since it has no way of knowing otherwise. As you're linking C++ code, you have to use the option `--driver-name c++` to set the driver. If you happen to have the MinGW executables with a prefix you have to include it too in the driver name (e.g. `i686-mingw32-c++` instead of `c++`) and you may need to use the option `--dlltool-name` too.

Try using these two lines instead of the one you posted:

```
g++ -c CXXFLAGS DEFINES INCLUDES -o library.o library.cpp
dllwrap -o library.dll --driver-name c++ --def DEF_FILE OBJECT_FILES LIBS -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup
```

The first one generates an object file from the code of `library.cpp` and the second one assembles the dynamic library. The `OBJECT_FILES` thing (which I assume to be other object files you generated previously) should have `library.o` there too.

That said, I have to tell you dllwrap was already [deprecated](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-binutils@gnu.org/msg01469.html) in 2006 and there is no documentation on it in the official binutils package; to get some info you may call it with `--help` as usual. It can generate an import library in case you need it too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, unless the symbols are specified in the `def` file they're not exported, even the ones from the libraries. I will use dllwrap, I'm using binutils 2.20 and dllwrap is still there so maybe it's still maintained.

If it's deprecated... shouldn't there be a way to do the same thing using only gcc and cia?

Comment: @James the preferred way is to mark the symbols in the source with `dllexport/dllimport` and have symbol visibility handled like that.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why there's no real answer to this, but here's what worked for me:

1. Compilation of your object files:

   ```
   g++ -O0 -gdwarf-4 dll\dllmain.cpp -c -o dllmain.o
   ```
2. Linking (`-Wl,--exclude-all-symbols` is important):

   ```
   g++ -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--out-implib,libsomelib.a -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -shared dllmain.o -o somelib.dll
   ```

Then you choose which functions to export directly in source code of your DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void someExportedFunction() {
    MessageBox(NULL, "msgbox", "msgbox", MB_OK);
}

void nonExportedFunction() {
    MessageBox(NULL, "notexported", "notexported", MB_OK);
}
```

Verification:

```
C:\libtest>pedump -E somelib.dll

=== EXPORTS ===

# module "somelib.dll"
# flags=0x0  ts="2014-02-20 08:37:48"  version=0.0  ord_base=1
# nFuncs=1  nNames=1

  ORD ENTRY_VA  NAME
    1     1570  _Z20someExportedFunctionv
```

(`pedump` = http://pedump.me)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the option `-Wl,--retain-symbols-file=file` and then list the symbols you want to keep (one per line) in `file`.  This will cause the linker to discard all other symbols, keeping just the ones you want.

Comment: @paulm: In the [docs for GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

Answer (score 3):

This is a recurrent issue. Here are two related questions in SO:

- [Removing exported symbols from a DLL and its associated import library (VS8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415588/removing-exported-symbols-from-a-dll-and-its-associated-import-library-vs8)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586262/how-to-know-exported-symbols-for-windows-dll-from-linux-mingw/9600759#9600759 (DEAD)

and outside SO:

- http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/unwanted-exported-symbols-in-a-DLL-which-statically-links-to-Boost-Library-td2590169.html
- http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1134/

i.e. global / local exporting on the Windows platform is not handled at the linker level but but the provision of a `.def` file to complement the `.dll`.

Lacking a good answer, I did a python script that takes care of removing stuff from the dll export table, you can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/dsign/export_controls/raw/646f93ac6a1d17bdbec637420a29f5249836b180/exports_control.py) .

Answer (score 2):

Did you read this on the page you supplied  alink to, regarding behaviour if --export-all-symbols is not used explicitly - auto export is disabled if:

> Any symbol in any object file was
>   marked with the __declspec(dllexport)
>   attribute.

Have you tried explicitly exporting only the functions you are interested in? It's very easy to get names wrong in  DEF  file, because of mangling, so this method should be more reliable.

Comment: I've marked like that the symbols I want to be exported, and they are, but I can't access the sources of the libraries I'm linking to. I can't take that marking away from there.

Comment: @James You can't take away exporting once it has been done, I'm afraid.

Comment: Aha, thank you then, so the symbols exported by other libraries must remain.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I've only done this on Linux, but AFAIK it should work on Windows as well

You can use the `-fvisibility=hidden` option; for more info see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help in a Windows environment (at least with my compiler). I'm getting "visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored" warnings even in a foo test, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [version script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/LD-Version-Scripts.html) in GNU LD to create an allowlist of exported symbols.

Suppose that there is a `library_somefunc` function in the `library.cpp` and you want to export only that symbol. You can prepare such a plain text file called `version-script.txt`:

```
{
    global:
        library_somefunc;

    local:
        *;
};
```

By specifying `library_somefunc` as global, you indicate that this symbol should be exported in the dynamic link library. We specify `*` as local so that no other symbols are exported.

Then, build the dll with the following command:

```bash
g++ -shared CXXFLAGS DEFINES INCLUDES -o library.dll library.cpp DEF_FILE OBJECT_FILES LIBS -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,--version-script=version-script.txt
```

You can use [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to check if the DLL file exports symbols correctly.